# How to deploy a compiled application without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windowsiot

When I open [a sample Blinky application](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/BlinkyHeadless/CS) in Visual Studio, compile and run it, it gets automatically deployed to the target configured WindowsIoT device. After that, on Windows 10 machine where I compile it, the application binaries are located in the bin sub-folder of the project folder as one would expect.

I would like to automate the deployment, so that I could run deployment code
    *without* Visual Studio, specify target device and the binaries location and it would deploy it. I cannot find any API that allows
    to deploy apps to Windows IoT, how do I do that?

This shiny Windows IoT stuff is a new area, and there is not a lot of info available apart from the samples and the [getting started page](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/StartCoding.htm). Any pointers are appreciated.

*Update:* As noted in comments, once one start thinking of mass production, they will probably need to conciser [ICD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This, is not, however the problem I'm trying to solve currently. I would like to figure out how I can provide Over-the-Air updates to my UWP application running on Raspberry Pi and Windows IoT. I also would you like to know how I can automate build / deployment in general, but that may be automatically solved if I have a proper OTA solution.

Comment: Hmya, using VS is just fine to deploy test builds.  The next step up is very different, you now start to think about building and selling your IoT device by the dozens or thousands.  Which involves not just deploying your app, you also need to deploy the OS.  You use the ICD tool for that, the page that describes installing the IoT app into the image [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant, well, one wants to do OTA updates, it still requires knowledge how to deploy without VS, and ICD is not much help here, since I can't get every device in the field back to the office to get serviced, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set of instructions on how to do it, which can be found in the same github repo you are linking in your question, but [in a different folder](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AppInstall). Note, that you need an appx for these instructions to work, and it's not created by the solution build by default.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx) provide (non IoT specific) instructions on using VS to build the appx. And [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/02/12/create-a-windows-store-appx-package-and-sign-it.aspx) post talks about the command line tool that can be used for making appx.

Note, that the last two links are also talking about publishing an application to app store, so you'll need to make some mental adjustments around that.